# Exporting Net Use results in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0, network-share, net-use, network-shares

I have a log off script that saves mapped network shares to a txt file:

```
#File path for save
$TxtPath = "C:\temp\" + "$env:UserName" + ".txt"

#Clear existing entries in file
Clear-Content -Path $TxtPath

#Return drive letters
$DriveList = Get-PSDrive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' | Select-String -Pattern '^[a-b:d-g:i-z]$'

#Get path for each drive letter and save in specific format (letter;path)
Foreach($Item in $DriveList){
$DrivePath = (Get-PSDrive $Item).DisplayRoot
$Entry = -join($Item, ":", ";", $DrivePath)
Add-Content -Path $TxtPath -Value ($Entry)
}
```

I then have a logon script that resets and maps these drives:

```
#File path for user drive paths
$TxtPath = "C:\temp\" + "$env:UserName" + ".txt"

#Get current drives
$DriveList = Get-PSDrive | Select-Object -ExpandProperty 'Name' | Select-String -Pattern '^[a-b:d-g:i-z]$'

#Remove current drives
ForEach($Item in $DriveList){
    $Drive = -join($Item, ":")
    net use $Drive /delete
}

#Map network drives from file
ForEach($Line in Get-Content $TxtPath) {
    $DriveLetter,$DrivePath = $Line.split(';')
    net use $DriveLetter $DrivePath
}
```

My issue is that, because I am using net use to delete and map the drives (in the logon script), that the Get-PSDrive function in the logoff script does not return a drive path. The reason I am using net use over Remove-PSDrive is due to  the drive not being fully removed (still shows on the users device).

Is anyone able to tell me how I can capture the Remote Name value for a network share when I look it up using net use (net use Z:)? If I can simply capture this path (and only this path) I will be able to write that to the text file along with the drive letter and thus solve my issue.

I know I can capture the results of net use by saving the data to a file:

```
net use x: > C:\Temp\output.txt
```

However I am unable to save this data / single line of required information to a variable. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Why do you not use the persistent paramter?

Comment: Where? The purpose of these scripts is to enable a very basic form of profile management - so the drives will follow the user no matter what device the log into...

Comment: ok, when you change devices persistent will no help.

Comment: Yep... hence the script... do you have any thoughts about how I could capture the variable from net use?

Comment: I can not reproduce your problem. when I use `net use` and after that search for the drives with `get-psdrive` I get the root path.

Comment: Steps to reproduce: map network drives -> run logoff script -> run logon script -> run logoff script -> check file with mappings. I have reproduced on two devices, one running our company SOE and another running a vanilla Win10 1709 build.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is look directly in the registry:

```
Get-ChildItem "HKCU:Network\" |
    ForEach-Object {
        [PsCustomObject]@{
            DriveLetter = $_.PSChildName
            RemotePath = (Get-ItemProperty $_.PSPath).RemotePath
        }
    }
```

This will give output like this:

```
DriveLetter RemotePath                
----------- ----------                
M           \\server1\share1 
N           \\server2\share2   
O           \\server3\share3
```

To save to file, I'd recommend CSV format by adding this after the last bracket:

```
| Export-Csv <path>\MappedDrive.csv
```

You can then easily import the data again with `Import-Csv`.